# google app engine dev app server do not allow to change datastore file path

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu

try 1 with sqlite and datastore path option

```
WARNING  2011-07-13 05:01:06,169 datastore_file_stub.py:511] Could not read datastore data from /home/gopal/temp.sqldb
INFO     2011-07-13 05:01:06,170 rdbms_sqlite.py:58] Connecting to SQLite database '' with file '/tmp/dev_appserver.rdbms'
```

try 2 with clear datastore and path option

```
INFO     2011-07-13 05:00:28,059 dev_appserver.py:4578] Attempting to remove file at /home/gopal/temp.sqldb
WARNING  2011-07-13 05:00:28,059 datastore_file_stub.py:511] Could not read datastore data from /home/gopal/temp.sqldb
INFO     2011-07-13 05:00:28,060 rdbms_sqlite.py:58] Connecting to SQLite database '' with file '/tmp/dev_appserver.rdbms'
INFO     2011-07-13 05:00:28,079 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:637] Running application inqzinwebsite on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
```

I am using google app engine on ubuntu 11.04 and custom python2.5 install. The problem I have is, whenever I restart dev app server, old data got deleted. How Do I prevent that ? ( either by changing path of database file OR somehow telling ubuntu to not to delete file in tmp folder. ) but I could not able to do either.  Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

edit:
I am using kay framework.

```
python2.5 manage.py runserver --datastore_path=/home/gopal/temp.sqldb --use_sqlite
python2.5 manage.py runserver --datastore_path=/home/gopal/temp.sqldb --clear_datastore
python2.5 manage.py runserver --datastore_path=/home/gopal/temp.sqldb
```

Comment: What are the actual command lines you're using?

Comment: The 'connecting to sqlite database' line is unrelated to the sqlite datastore backend, and is actually part of the (unreleased) SQL backend support. Either of the first two commands should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I tried using direct dev app server instead of manage script from kay framework and it works. So I think problem was with kay framework. Relevant issue added to kay bug list. sorry for question.

http://code.google.com/p/kay-framework/issues/detail?id=109

Answer (score 2):

`/tmp/dev_appserver.rdbms` is default location of your datastore file in linux.Whenever you restart your machine, /tmp/ directory is cleaned. That's why you cannot see your old datas.
Change the datastore path to someother location other than tmp/ that should sove the issue.

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore myapp
```

Comment: I have tried to change it. It is not working. Check the edited part of the post for a different command I have tried.